# [__NSCFType searchKeyword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d8eb80

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector, uncaught-exception

The following code is to add a subview to current view from storyboard:

```
EventSearchViewController* view1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];

[view1 setBookingSystem:system];

[self.view addSubview:view1.view];
```

In the view "view1", there is a textField. The following is a IBAction to the textField and the event is "Did end on exit".

```
-(IBAction)searchKeyword:(id *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"searchKeyword");
}
```

The following is the error message.

> 2012-05-26 20:26:47.369 OnlineBooking[6607:f803] -[__NSCFType searchKeyword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d8eb80
>
> 2012-05-26 20:26:47.369 OnlineBooking[6607:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate:  -[__NSCFType searchKeyword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d8eb80

Answer (score 12):

You need to retain your `EventSearchViewController`, or keep a strong reference to it if you're using ARC.  If you assign it to `view1` as a local variable, it's not going to be around any more when `searchKeyword:` gets called.  (The error shows that its memory has been released and re-used for a different type of object.)

Comment: thank you very much. I keep a strong reference to view1, then the error solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I never called

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

before I called

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

again.