# Wiring NSToolBarItem with XIBs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

For some reason I'm having a very difficult time wiring my NSToolbarItem to an IBAction.

I'm using an `NSWindowController` with its own XIB. The `NSToolbar` is dropped into the XIB, and I added the `NSToolbarItem` without issue. This whole `NSWindowController` is created by a master NSViewController when an image is clicked.

The problem lies with the new button not sending. I unchecked "`Autovalidates`" and checked "`Selectable`" so that I could actually click the button.

However when pressed, I receive "`unrecognized selector sent to instance`".

I've wired this several times over through the XIB interface to make sure I wasn't messing up.

What's going on? Thank you.

Full error:

```
-[__NSCFType buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101915010
```

Comment: can you show us the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate class does not know the selector you've wired. Either your delegate is wrong or you've got a typing error in your method.

Check the signature of the Method you've declared in your headerfile vs. its implementation in the class file. Perhaps you forgot to declare a parameter.

edit:
the class type where the selector is called looked weird, so I googled `__nscftype unrecognized selector`. here are some suggestions, it seems like your delegate is already disposed :
http://imlocation.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/strange-objects-nscftype-indicate-memory-management-bugs/
[[__NSCFType searchKeyword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d8eb80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766327/nscftype-searchkeyword-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x6d8eb80)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The delegate on the toolbar is set to the File's Owner. The method is simply -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender. The selector on the toolbarItem was dragged and dropped onto the IBAction.

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right track, the NSWindowController was being released for some reason after the NSWindow was created.